# How to detect whether user select picture or video from library while using UIImagePickerController in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using UIImagePickerController in my ios application to give an option to user to select photo or video from photo library. I'm restricting the video to 1 minute.
Here is my code:

In a button action:

```
- (void)getPictureOrVideoFromLibrary {

    CFStringRef mTypes[2] = { kUTTypeImage, kUTTypeMovie };
    CFArrayRef mTypesArray = CFArrayCreate(CFAllocatorGetDefault(), (const void**)mTypes, 2, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = (__bridge NSArray*)mTypesArray;
    CFRelease(mTypesArray);

    imagePickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 60.0f;
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;

    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I want show both pictures and videos in photolibrary, so i have used both `kUTTypeImage` and `kUTTypeMovie`.
Here i'm setting `videoMaximumDuration` to `60.0f` and `allowsEditing` to `YES` because i want to restrict the video length to 1 minute.

**The problem i'm facing**:
when user selects video from library there is no issue, but if user selects picture from library i'm getting problem, a rectangle box on picture.

The Picker shows like this(With videos and pictures)[screenshot1]:

[image]

when user selects video it is showing like this(It's working as expected):

[image]

When user selects picture it is showing like this [screenshot2]:

[image]

I don't want to show rectangle crop box here.

After user press '**Choose**', i will be able to detect whether it is photo or video in delegate method 'didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo'.

But i want to know whether it is photo or video from screenshot1 to screenshot2. so that i can set `allowsediting` to NO to get rid of that rectangle box.

Is it possible?

I don't want to show both options as 'Select photo from library', 'Select video from library'.
I just want to show only one option as 'Select Photo or Video from library'.

Is there any way to detect whether user selects picture or video, or is it possible to get rid of that rectangle box?

Is it possible to achieve?

I need your valuable suggestions.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you added delegate methods ?

Comment: are you using sinlge button for photo and libary or there is two button one for "select photo" another one is for "select video" ?

Comment: @sheshnath. I have only single button that loads both pictures and videos from library..

Comment: @AshokKumarS: can you see both the picture and videos in picker view ?

Comment: Yes i can see both. @V-Xtreme

Comment: @AshokKumarS : cant say without trying the code, But can you try to print all the keys of info dictionary . Also dont know how are you fetching video/image from the info directory

Comment: by looking at the docs it seems like you have fetch the video using key UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL and image using key UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage

Comment: Thanks. @V-Xtreme..I think you are not getting my problem or my question was unclear..I have updated it. please check it once.

Comment: @AshokKumarS which library is this?

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 It's apple's UIImagePickerController from UIKit framework: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: @AshokKumarS that range one?

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 It's from the same Apple's framework only. The range slider is for the user to clip the longer videos as we have specified 'videoMaximumDuration' as '60'.

Answer (score 5):

check like this on delegate method

```
   - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)pickerImage didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

  // UIImagePickerControllerMediaType
 if(info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType]==kUTTypeImage)
 {
    //image
 }
 else
 {
    //video
 }
}
```

1) add MobileCoreServices.framework

2) import below header file. MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h

Comment: Thanks @shesh nath..I know this method..I think you are not getting my problem or my question was unclear..I have updated it. please check it once.

Comment: `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any?' and 'CFString'`

Answer (score 2):

Just Little bit change in @shesh nath's answer. I just convert **kUTTypeImage** to `NSString` to solve this warning :

> Comparison of distinct pointer types ('id _Nullable' and 'CFStringRef'
>   (aka 'const struct __CFString *'))

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)imagePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info {

    if([info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] isEqualToString:(__bridge NSString *)(kUTTypeImage)])
    {
        NSLog(@"Image");
        //image
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Video");
        //video
    }
}
```

And don't forget to add MobileCoreServices framework.